# $9 \mid 4n^2 + 15n - 1$ for $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: induction

How to prove by induction that $9 \mid 4n^2 + 15n - 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$?

For $n = 1$

$4 \cdot 1^2 + 15 \cdot 1 - 1 = 18$

For $n \ge 2$

If $4n^2 + 15n - 1 = 9k$ then $4(n+1)^2 + 15(n+1) - 1 = 4n^2 + 23n + 18 = 9k + 8n + 19$

Comment: Hello. What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I think this is false, since for $n=3$ you get 80.

Comment: @RolfHoyer You're right :(. I struggled with this for 1 hour and it seems like my math textbook is wrong.

Comment: I think  he meant $4^n +15n -1$ is divisible by 9.

Comment: Maybe you meant this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404305/9-mid-4n2-15n-1-for-n-in-mathbb-n?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $4n^2+15n-1$ is divisible by $9$, then it's also divisible by $3$; however
$$
4n^2+15n-1\equiv n^2-1\pmod{3}
$$
but $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ if and only if $3\nmid n$. So, for $n=3k$, the number $4n^2+15n-1$ is not divisible by $3$ and, of course, not divisible by $9$ either.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true buddy, take $n=3$. In general if $n=3t$ it wont be true. Greetings!

Comment: Hey, why so violent. And, why delete it? xd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27212/discussion-between-unperrito-and-ahna-akbar-perez).